# Setting textview visibility inside retrofit on failure callback

Tags: android, android-fragments, textview, android-view, android-runonuithread

I am trying to set the visibility of a `Textview` depending on the response returned by **Retrofit** . `onFailure`, I am setting the visibility to visible `tv_no_cat.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` However, this does not work. I am doing the same with a `ContentLoadingProgressBar` and it's working appropriately. Here is my code

```
public void onFailure(Call<List<MoviesCategory>> call, Throwable t) {
            tv_no_cat.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); ////This does not work
            Boolean x = tv_no_cat.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE;

            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Network Error "+x, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    //This shows true
            tv_no_cat.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
            videoLoadingPb.setVisibility(View.GONE); //This works
        }
```

My guess is that am trying to set the `textview` which is on UI thread from another thread. If so, why is it working for the `ContentLoadingProgressBar`?

Here is my xml for the 2 views

```
<android.support.v4.widget.ContentLoadingProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/loading_categories"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="visible" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_below="@id/loading_categories"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="No Movie Category Found"
        android:id="@+id/tv_no_cat"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:visibility="gone"
        />
```

Any help on how I can set the `textview` Visibility to `VISIBLE` is welcome.

Comment: android:id="@+id/loading_categories"


try to print its visibility like
.getVisibility()

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](http://square.github.io/retrofit/):

> On Android, callbacks will be executed on the main thread...

So this is not your issue, and I'm doubtful that it's related to Retrofit, especially when it works for another view. Please make sure that there are no problem in your xml design, and that there are no other methods that affect this view's visibility.

Comment: I have added code for the affected views. Please help me have a look at them

Comment: Your xml contains both `RelativeLayout` and `LinearLayout` attributes so it's unclear what you actually use. If it's `RelativeLayout`, replace `layout_gravity` with the 'layout_alignParentBottom'.

Comment: Okey. ill do that. However, if I do `tv_no_cat.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` inside the `onCreateView`, it shows the textview

Comment: So my previous suggestion is unnecessary. Anyway, it's definitely not related to Retrofit - you provided 2 evidences (the fact that another view "works" as expected and the Toast check). It's not something that I can help you within a SO question scope, but my general advice is to look for flaws in the UI (whether in xml or in your Activity code). Maybe another view is covering your TextView or pushing it off screen.

Comment: Thanks man. I have tried doing this on an Activity and it is working. Would the reason be that I am doing this on a fragment??

Comment: Not directly. Perhaps your fragment does not have enough room to show its content.

Answer (score 0):

are registering Textview inside Oncreate or some where else ?
And this code you are using inside activity of fragment ?

Please check this ...

tv_no_cat=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_no_cat);(Inside Activity)

tv_no_cat=(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.tv_no_cat);(Inside Fragment )

Comment: Thanks a lot but In this case, casting is just adding redundancy and I don't think it will help.